# Is it fine to SetActive in Update()?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know unity optimizes `Update()` method and that's why it is ok to set a variable without any condition there. But what about methods, especially `gameObject.SetActive`? It is really handy when you need to bind GO activity to some condition, but how does it affect performance? For instance, in UI `SetActive` causes canvas redraw. But I guess it's not a problem if Unity does optimize the method in `Update()`. So, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Any code you write in the Update will be called every frame. In general I avoid using Update method if possible.

With Events and Coroutines you can run your code only when needed. It makes the code more efficient and readable.

For example instead of updating the health bar every frame in Update you can write a Coroutine that will run only on PlayerDamaged event when the player gets hit.

If your code/app is small you won't see a big difference in performance so it doesn't matter that much but it is a better practice to only use Update for the code that really needs to be called every frame.

Answer (score 0):

ya it is fine but recommend using **FixedUpdate()** instead of **Update()**

Comment: Well, it probably depends on purposes. E.g. it is better to update UI in Update. Or is there any special reason to use FixedUpdate?

Comment: @eastwing Nothing special about FixedUpdate. It has the frequency of the physics system; it is called every fixed frame-rate frame so not every frame like Update.